# Getting Ng/Rx component store error "MyStore has not been initialized yet" when calling patch

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-component-store

I am using NgRx component store `14.3.0`.

I extend the Component store, like the following

```
@Injectable()
  export abstract class MyStoreBase<T extends MyStateBase> extends 
     ComponentStore<T> implements OnDestroy {
```

Sometimes just after creating it's owning component I am getting the error "MyStore has not been initialized yet" (MyStore being the name of my store)

I have setup code something like the following... I am using also using NgRx store, where I get some other global state, and then call my Component store methods

```
constructor(
private store$: Store<State>) {
 super(INITIAL_BASE_STATE as T);

 // Was getting some errors about calling patch before store was initialised, so make
 // the subscriptions async    
 setTimeout(() => this.initialise(), 100);
 }

public initialise(): void {
  // Subscribe to updated
  this.subs.sink = this.store$.select(fromApp.getConfig).pipe(filter(x => !!x)).subscribe(config => {       
  this.getData('');
});

private getData = this.effect((trigger$: Observable<string>) => trigger$.pipe(
  tap(() => {
    this.patchState((state) => ({ ...state, isRequesting: true }));
    ....
}),
```

So it is the call to `patchState` inside the tap that is causing the issue. I have used the `setTimeout` to try and get around this issue (but it is not enough)

This is the line where the error is occurring...

[image]

So, if I look for where `this.isInitialized` is being set I see this in the constructor (and I am passing a default state)

[image]

And then if we look at the initState we see..

[image]

So `this.isInitialized` is being set to true in what looks like some async call.

I thought I could subscribe to the `this.stateSubject` but it does not seem to be available.

My question is, how can I then know the store is ready to use?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm having the same issue where the @ngrx/component-store initializes fine when I fill it the first time with data from an http call. Then if I add user changes to session storage, and on page refresh grab from session storage instead, when I try to fill the component store from session storage data, the component store is not initialized.

Comment: No, I still have the code ```setTimeout(() => this.initialise(), 300);``` in there :-(

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago ngrx team added new lifecycle hooks like component store
ngrxOnStateInit https://ngrx.io/guide/component-store/lifecycle#eager-state-init,
your initialise method should probably be the implementation of ngrxOnStateInit

```
public ngrxOnStateInit(): void {
  // Subscribe to updated
  this.subs.sink = this.store$.select(fromApp.getConfig).pipe(filter(x => !!x)).subscribe(config => {       
  this.getData('');
});
```